# Popup banner on a page to announce when other people are looking at the same page

Tags: ajax, web-applications

New customers of company X must be investigated to find out if they are legitimate. A web page lists all the customers that have not yet been investigated, each one hotlinked to a page with details about that customer. It often happens that two investigators visit the details page for the same new customer at the same time and investigate the same customer independently. This is a waste of time.

Several investigators have suggested that a dynamic HTML banner could pop up on the customer detail page whenever two or more investigators are looking at the same detail page. If investigator X is looking at a certain page, and then investigator Y navigates to the same page, Y would see a banner at the top of the page warning them that X was already looking at this page, and a similar banner would pop up on X's page to warn them that Y had started looking at it. This seems like a reasonable idea. (The ZenDesk ticket management system uses a similar popup to help prevent two customer service agents from trying to service the same ticket at the same time.)

Before I go and implement a lot of stuff, is there anything that does something like that that I could use right out of the can? Or is there anything that handles just the front-end parts of this, to which I could attach a homegrown backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I didn't receive an answer, I went ahead with plan B, which was to go ahead and implement "a lot of stuff". This is now  available at  https://github.com/ZipRecruiter/2banner under a free license.

The stuff I implemented consists of three components:

- A backend database API for storing information about which users looked at which pages and when
- A middle API server that can answer queries about who is looking at each page
- A JavaScript thingy for the web page that sends of an AJAX request to the API server and then pops up a banner if the response indicates that someone else is looking at the same page

The backend uses Perl's `DBIx::Class` library.  The API server is designed as a plugin component for Perl's `Catalyst` framework.  The front-end uses jQuery.  All three of these components are more or less independent, and any of them could be replaced with something else, so it is my hope that people will be able to use some of this even if they can't use the whole thing.

The package is called `2banner`. The source code, with detailed installation and usage instructions, is available for free distribution under the BSD three-clause license, courtesy of my employer, [ZipRecruiter](http://ziprecruiter.com).

> https://github.com/ZipRecruiter/2banner

Share and enjoy.